# How to remove this green area when using vim?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image]

I was using WSL(window subsystem for linux) Ubuntu, and i was editing a code with vim.

Every time I look down and look up again, these green area has generated.

There is no effect of green area, but it really bothers me.

How can I remove this? Do I modify the vimrc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Microsoft has a bug in their terminal.  Their terminal claims it is of type `xterm-256color`, and terminals of that type are required to support a feature called background color erase (BCE).  However, Microsoft failed to implement that feature properly.  Vim tries to use it to clear the background, and nothing happens.

Fortunately, Microsoft has [fixed this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/832).  You should try to make sure you're using the latest Windows 10 version, the latest Microsoft Terminal version, and the latest version of WSL.  If that fails, you can add `set t_ut=""` in your `.vimrc`, and see if that fixes it.  However, if you do that, it's possible other programs will have the same issue until you have a fixed version of the terminal.

Comment: I  solved my problem by adding set t_ut = "" to  .vimrc thank you!